# R library eurostat: different behaviour on Windows and Linux/Mac RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

There is different output of R eurostat library on Windows and Linux/Mac RStudio.

While Linux/Mac downloads variables as texts (factors), Windows returns only factors id as integer.

Try this code please:

```
library(eurostat)
dat <- get_eurostat("tsdtr210")
head(dat)
str(dat)
```

This is result on Linux/Mac RStudio:

```
> dat <- get_eurostat("tsdtr210")
> head(dat)
  unit vehicle geo       time values
1   PC BUS_TOT  AT 1990-01-01   11.0
2   PC BUS_TOT  BE 1990-01-01   10.6
3   PC BUS_TOT  BG 1990-01-01     NA
4   PC BUS_TOT  CH 1990-01-01    3.7
5   PC BUS_TOT  CY 1990-01-01     NA
6   PC BUS_TOT  CZ 1990-01-01     NA
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2520 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ unit   : Factor w/ 1 level "PC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ vehicle: Factor w/ 3 levels "BUS_TOT","CAR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ geo    : Factor w/ 35 levels "AT","BE","BG",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ time   : Date, format: "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" ...
 $ values : num  11 10.6 NA 3.7 NA NA 9.1 11.3 NA 32.4 ...
```

Windows RStudio returns this result:

```
> dat <- get_eurostat("tsdtr210")
> head(dat)
  unit vehicle geo       time values
1    1       1   1 1990-01-01   11.0
2    1       1   2 1990-01-01   10.6
3    1       1   3 1990-01-01     NA
4    1       1   4 1990-01-01    3.7
5    1       1   5 1990-01-01     NA
6    1       1   6 1990-01-01     NA
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2520 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ unit   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ vehicle: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ geo    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ time   : Date, format: "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" "1990-01-01" ...
 $ values : num  11 10.6 NA 3.7 NA NA 9.1 11.3 NA 32.4 ...
```

Do you know how to change it on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Install development version from github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ropengov/eurostat")
```

Function get_eurostat() contains `stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()` parameter and it works now.